# How to add object values to viewmodel with List<object>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

[image]I have a view model and trying to return a linq object, I'm not sure how to add a list object in the linq return query.
I have attached the sample code for better understanding.

View model:

```
public class BusinessAnalysisViewModel
{
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
    public List<BAQandR> QuestionResponseIds { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
public class BAQandR
{
    public int BAQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string BAResponse { get; set; }
    public int? BAFinPreviousYr { get; set; }
    public int? BAFinCurrentYr { get; set; }
}
```

Linq query:

```
public BusinessAnalysisViewModel GetBusinessAnalysisInfo(Guid userID)
    {
        using (var ctxAdmin = new MemberDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.CONFIG_KEY_MEMBER_CONNECTION_STRING].ToString()))
        {
            var model = (from ba in ctxAdmin.Business_Analysis
                         where ba.User_Guid == userID
                         select new BusinessAnalysisViewModel
                         {
                             UserGuid = ba.User_Guid,
                             CreateDate = ba.CreateDate,
                             UpdateDate = ba.UpdateDate,

                             QuestionResponseIds =
                         });
            return model;
        }
    }
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I'm expecting the below kind of json result from my logic.

```html
{
  "UserGuid": "000000000-4D3B-4598-A1FC-6B7B1D6D99D2",
  "CreateDate": "2019-05-22T18:52:14.458Z",
  "UpdateDate": "2019-05-22T18:52:14.458Z",
  "QuestionResponseIds": [
    {
      "BAQuestionId": 1,
      "BAResponse": 1,
      "BAFinPreviousYr": "",
      "BAFinPreviousYr": ""
    },
    {
      "BAQuestionId": 1,
      "BAResponse": 1,
      "BAFinPreviousYr": "",
      "BAFinPreviousYr": ""
    },
    {
      "BAQuestionId": 1,
      "BAResponse": 1,
      "BAFinPreviousYr": "",
      "BAFinPreviousYr": ""
    },
    {
      "BAQuestionId": 1,
      "BAResponse": 1,
      "BAFinPreviousYr": "",
      "BAFinPreviousYr": ""
    }
  ]  
}
```

I have changed the model as shown below,

```
public class UserBusinessAnalysis
{
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int BAQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string BAResponse { get; set; }
    public int? BAFinPreviousYr { get; set; }
    public int? BAFinCurrentYr { get; set; }        
}
```

Linq as shown below,

```
public List<UserBusinessAnalysis> GetBusinessAnalysisInfoByUserId(Guid userID)
    {
        using (var ctxAdmin = new MemberDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.CONFIG_KEY_MEMBER_CONNECTION_STRING].ToString()))
        {
            var model = (from ba in ctxAdmin.Business_Analysis
                         where ba.User_Guid == userID
                         select new UserBusinessAnalysis
                         {
                             UserGuid = ba.User_Guid,
                             CreateDate = ba.CreateDate,
                             UpdateDate = ba.UpdateDate,
                             BAQuestionId = ba.B_Analysis_Question_id,
                             BAResponse = ba.B_Analysis_Response,
                             BAFinPreviousYr = ba.Fin_Review_Previous_Year,
                             BAFinCurrentYr = ba.Fin_Review_Current_Year
                         }).ToList();
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I dont see any list. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: public List<BAQandR> QuestionResponseIds { get; set; } is the list object, please review the viewmodel.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots when you can copy the code over, it makes it harder to help you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply add your list property to the result

```
using (var ctxAdmin = new MemberDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.CONFIG_KEY_MEMBER_CONNECTION_STRING].ToString()))
{
    var model = (from ba in ctxAdmin.Business_Analysis
                 where ba.User_Guid == userID
                 select new BusinessAnalysisViewModel
                 {
                     UserGuid = ba.User_Guid,
                     CreateDate = ba.CreateDate,
                     UpdateDate = ba.UpdateDate,

                     QuestionResponseIds = ba.QuestionResponseIds
                 });
    return model;
}
```

If your types don't match, you will need to do another projection

```
using (var ctxAdmin = new MemberDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.CONFIG_KEY_MEMBER_CONNECTION_STRING].ToString()))
{
    var model = (from ba in ctxAdmin.Business_Analysis
                 where ba.User_Guid == userID
                 select new BusinessAnalysisViewModel
                 {
                     UserGuid = ba.User_Guid,
                     CreateDate = ba.CreateDate,
                     UpdateDate = ba.UpdateDate,

                     QuestionResponseIds = ba.QuestionResponseIds.Select(r => new BAQandR { /* copy fields here */ }).ToList()
                 });
    return model;
}
```

Comment: QuestionResponseIds is of type list<BAQandR>,
When I type in "ba." I don't see QuestionResponseIds, because the result would be from database right.
I have added the picture.

Comment: I'm using linq to sql classes, I have attached the class, let me know if that helps.

Comment: You posted the private backing fields, I can only guess what the public properties are.

Comment: I have added a expected result, 
I'm not sure how to get the public properties from linq to sql class.

Comment: @AnanthAsamani Updated the answer a bit, but without being able to see all the models involved in their entirety, there's not much more I can do

Comment: I have mentioned all the models that are involved in the logic, I don't think I have missed something here.
Did you see the expected result, is it possible with the model I defined?